# Como comparar 2 cadenas en java pero que 2 palabras de las mismas sean libres

Tags: java, array, netbeans, string

Buen día y muchas gracias por sus respuestas de antemano.

Tengo que hacer un programa en java que me permita comparar 2 cadenas (una predefinida y correcta)  y otra que ingresará el usuario, el tema  es que en esa, digamos frase, 2 palabras deben ser libres (pueden variar en longitud y tipo de dato) es decir el usuario puede poner cualquier cosa  ya sea que coincida o no con lo que está en la cadena predefinída pero lo demás si debe ser igual... Pongo un ejemplo:

Frase predefinída: el bosque 3sta muy grande y obscuro además de silencioso.

Frase dada por el usuario: el bosque 3sta muy pequeño y claro además de silencioso.

Obsevece como la palabra  "grande" y "obscuro"  cambiaron, el  resultado de esa comparación es correcto ya que esas palabras son las libres...

Como puedo hacerlo?  Hasta ahora meto ambas cadenas en 2 arreglos y hace la comparación carácter por carácter... El problema viene después con las palabras libres y el texto con el que finaliza la frase.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera ademas de incluir el código que has intentado o que te da problemas. Saludos.

Comment: añade lo que has realizado por favor, añade el código, revisar [ask] saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya pasó un buen tiempo, no sé si lo habrás solucionado pero te doy una idea.

```
String correcta = "el bosque 3sta muy grande y obscuro además de silencioso"
String predifinida[] = correcta.split(" ");

//Aquí deberías de guardar el string que ingrese el usuario
String fraseUsuario = sc.nextLine();
String usuario[] = fraseUsuario.split(" ");

//Lo último que harías sería que compares ambos arreglos.
```

Saludos!!